# Google API Client - Understanding the code

Tags: java, google-api-java-client

I'm studying code from Google API client to be able to supply users in the Google groups, but I have two questions in the code.

#### Example

```
  /**
   * Exchange an authorization code for OAuth 2.0 credentials.
   *
   * @param authorizationCode Authorization code to exchange for OAuth 2.0
   *        credentials.
   * @return OAuth 2.0 credentials.
   * @throws CodeExchangeException An error occurred.
   */
  static Credential exchangeCode(String authorizationCode)
      throws CodeExchangeException {
    try {
      GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = getFlow();
      GoogleTokenResponse response =
          flow.newTokenRequest(authorizationCode).setRedirectUri(REDIRECT_URI).execute();
      return flow.createAndStoreCredential(response, null);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.err.println("An error occurred: " + e);
      throw new CodeExchangeException(null);
    }
  }
```

The snippet shows:

```
flow.createAndStoreCredential (response, null);
```

1. What does it do exactly? Stores in the database or in memory?
   What's database?
2. Where is null as parametro, can be passed a userId. How do I get this userid to pass as parameter?

Source: https://developers.google.com/drive/training/drive-apps/auth/credentials

Comment: [There is Javadoc for that class out there already...](http://javadoc.google-oauth-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/1.15.0-rc/com/google/api/client/auth/oauth2/AuthorizationCodeFlow.html?is-external=true)